# How do I layout code in a website with a common header import and jquery scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web

Let's say I have a website, and on every page I import a header and footer that are constant.

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />

<!-- Page contents go here. -->

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

I tend to put my javascript code in the page header, but I don't want every page to have to load the java script for every other page.  Equally, I don't really like my javascript being strewn throughout the content portion of all of my pages between the header/footer tags.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this?  I'm fairly new to web development, so I'm sure there's a standard convention I just haven't run across yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I do the same thing with php.

I split my header into two, so I include three items:

```
<jsp:include page="headerTop.jsp" />
<!-- custom CSS links go here -->
<!-- javascript references go here -->
<!-- custom javascript goes here -->
<jsp:include page="headerBottom.jsp" />

<!-- Page contents go here. -->

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

The `headerTop.jsp` file would contain the `<head>` tag, and the `headerBottom.jsp` file would contain the closing `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

combining with the first answer you could create a separate file **webresources.jsp** where you put in the css and javascript and then include the file to your pages:

```
<jsp:include page="headerTop.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="webresources.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="headerBottom.jsp" />

<!-- Page contents go here. -->

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```